# Change select tag attribute value

Tags: php, javascript

I have a drop down menu. By default it allows only one option to select among all. I want to create a checkbox which when checked should change that dropdown menu to allow multiple options to be selected. How can I achieve this?

```
<select id="test" name="host">
    <option value="host1">host1</option>
    <option value="host2">host2</option>
    .....
    .....
</select>
```

I want this to be changed to following on checkbox being checked.

```
<select id="test" name="host" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="host1">host1</option>
    <option value="host2">host2</option>
    .....
    .....
</select>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to do this without a page reload?

Comment: @MikeBrant: No, based on whether a checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: I guess you are not following my question.  I wanted to know if you wanted to have the checkbox selected and the `select` updated on the page without a page load (in which case you will need to use javascript). You didn't have javascript in your tags, so it was unclear if you wanted to click the checkbox and reload the page (i.e. modifiynig HTML source with PHP to add `mulitple`) or if you wanted to do this without the clumsy page reload. It sounds like you want javascript, which then brings up next question - do you want straight javascript or are you using jQuery or similar?

Comment: @MikeBrant: mike sorry for that.. yes i want that without a page reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use javascript for that..use a library called 'JQuery', it makes it very simple..

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QU9nw/)

```
$("#checkbox_id").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       $("#test").attr('multiple', 'multiple');
});
```

**Edit:** for reverting back..

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QU9nw/3)

```
$("#checkbox_test").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
       $("#test").attr('multiple', 'multiple');
    else
       $("#test").removeAttr('multiple');
});
```

Comment: On unchecking the checkbox, it should again revert back. How can we achieve that ?